# Change the Color for the VS2019's output

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

Is there a tool that enable to change the color for the output from wasp.net core webserver in VS 2019's output?

For instance if is it a sql statement the color should be yellow, otherwise all text should be black.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[VSColorOutput](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MikeWard-AnnArbor.VSColorOutput) extension can change the color of a line emitted to the output window based on specified rules.